# std::unique_ptr dereference exception not catch-ed in try-catch block

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, unique-ptr

So lets say I have:

```
struct test {
    bool a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<test> ptr;
    // don't init the ptr

    try
    {
        if (!ptr->a)
        {
            std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cout << "ex: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

So here I setup a unique pointer, but I don't init it (to simulate this in a larger code base) but I want to catch the exception.

The problem is that my exception is not called - I just get a crash (memory access fault)

I read a few similar questions (but not quite the same) that suggested that I pass the exception by reference - but this did not work.

So is it possible to catch a unique_ptr de-reference exception?

**EDIT:** I should add that this is on Windows 7 box running MSVS2012 executable - incase it is relevant!

Comment: De-referencing an uninitialised pointer is undefined behaviour and will not throw an exception.

Comment: @RichardCritten oh.... is there a way to do what I am trying to do? - I have a list of unique_ptr's - I was trying to avoid individually checking each one by putting a try block around it... but if it does not throw an exception then I guess I have to do `if (ptr) {...}`  around each one?

Comment: Why do you have owning smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`) that don't own anything? This feels like an XY-Problem.

Comment: @RichardCritten I am using smart pointers so that I don't have to worry so much about garbage collection and so on...  In my code when I create a new pointer the constructor (of the type pointed to ) can fail and if so the smart pointer is effectively nullptr. So I want to test this condition....

Comment: Throw an exception when the object being constructed fails and don't create a std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @RichardCritten ok, so I call a third party function that returns either a pointer or a nullptr. I could use raw pointers - but I wanted to use unique_ptr for the automatic garbage collection...  I believe that is one of the use-cases for unique_ptr? So the exception I want to trigger is when I get a nullptr returned...   Anyway, I guess the question is answered (i.e. can't do what I am trying) I will move the exception checking to test each pointer. Feel free to add your first comment as an answer, I'll mark it up.

Comment: You could create your own smart pointer that does the check/throw every time you use it. But that inevitably degrades performance somewhat. Incidentally `C++` will throw an exception (by default) if it fails to allocate your object when you create it.

Comment: Or wrap the third party creator function in a check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is it possible to catch a unique_ptr de-reference exception?

There is no `unique_ptr` dereference exception to catch.

As the [documentation says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*),

> > The behavior is undefined if `get() == nullptr`

You can easily write your own smart pointer with this Java-like behaviour, but it does mean paying for a test-and-branch on *every* dereference, which in general seems silly.

For the slightly different problem described in comments:

> I have a list of unique_ptr's - I was trying to avoid individually checking each one by putting a try block around it.

the sane solution is probably to check it once and not on every subsequent dereference:

```
if(any_of(begin(ptrs), end(ptrs), logical_not<unique_ptr<test>>{})
{
  throw MyNullPointerException();
}
```

Per subsequent comments, you could just add a check-and-throw wrapper to your constructing function.

In C++17 you can almost get what you want by instead returning an `optional<unique_ptr<test>>` (ie, it either contains a populated `unique_ptr`, or nothing at all: in that case, calling `value` to extract the `unique_ptr` would throw `std::bad_optional_access` if there isn't really one there).

If you can import ot (or don't have C++17), the [GSL](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) is probably even better with `gsl::not_null<T>`. For example, you could instead store these things in your container

```
using unique_not_null = std::unique_ptr<gsl::not_null<test>>;
```

Comment: *"ou could just add a check-and-throw wrapper to your constructing function"* - Like `gsl::not_null`?